# how to configure Spring Boot HikariPool for use with AWS RDS Proxy?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-rds, hikaricp, amazon-rds-proxy

I'm using RDS Proxy Endpoint(Writer/Reader, Reader).

1 writer-instance and 1 reader-instance are running. reader-instance CPU's nearly 90%.
so i've been trying to add 1 more reader instance.

I expected it distribute traffic immediately, automatically .

Hikari Settings -

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=100
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime: 3600000 ( 1 hour )
```

but It was not distribute traffic and i should wait end of hikari max-lifetime.
Should i change the max-lifetime to minimum? is this the best way?

ps) i prefer to use connection pooling because it is not serverless architecture, not micro services.
and if not using, because of not reuse connection, EKS pod's CPU will be 100%. so i would have to increase more and more eks pods count.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70607934/how-to-configure-spring-boot-hikaripool-for-use-with-aws-rds-proxy

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I read that answer. but if use single-connection, response latency is too high. (average 4 seconds per request) it is very slow.